# TypeScript tree typization

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

Below is a short example of a tree

```
interface TemplateRoot extends Template {}

class Template {
  #root: TemplateRoot | undefined

  get root (): TemplateRoot {
    return this.#root ?? this
  }

  set root (root: TemplateRoot | undefined) {
    this.#root = root
  }
}

class ChildOne extends Template {
  constructor (root?: Template) {
    super()
    this.root = root
  }

  method (): TemplateRoot {
    // do something
    console.log('Called method of ChildOne')
    return super.root
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends Template {
  constructor (root?: Template) {
    super()
    this.root = root
  }

  method (): TemplateRoot {
    // do something
    console.log('Called method of ChildTwo')
    return super.root
  }
}

class Parent extends Template {
  public $one: ChildOne
  public $two: ChildTwo

  constructor (root?: Template) {
    super()
    this.root = root

    this.$one = new ChildOne(this.root)
    this.$two = new ChildTwo(this.root)
  }

  method (): TemplateRoot {
    // do something
    console.log('Called method of Parent')
    return super.root
  }
}
```

When calling any method on a child instance it returns a parent instance (*if exists*) or itself. Nesting and sequence of instances in tree can be different. But they all extend the `Template` class and return the instance that was passed on creation, else it returns itself (*even if it is a child element*). Below is an example of usage:

```
const $parent = new Parent()
$parent.method()
$parent.$one.method().$two.method().method()
```

The JS code is correct and works fine. **But TS compiler doesn't see tree nodes**. For example, it doesn't see `$two` child, when calling `$parent.$one.method().$two` or `$parent.method().$two`

**How to write correct typization for the tree?**

Comment: Overriding an accessor type in subclasses makes this more complicated, since anything I do to try to modify your code ends up running afoul of this.  Unless this is *necessary* for your example, could you simplify it so it's a [mre] (emphasis on *minimal* there)?

Comment: In order to begin to get typings that work I had to make so many changes to your structure that it's barely even the same example; see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQ2M1N).  I don't know what to say about trying to give strong typings to code that uses `super` and mutates things with setters.  I'm happy to write up my version in an answer, if you want to see it, but otherwise I'm just going to shrug and move on, since I haven't found anything promising here.

Comment: @jcalz the hardest thing to me is childs: [usage](https://tsplay.dev/m0YGqW)
any node can belong to another node and methods returns root node, otherwise methods returns itself node. all nodes extends `Template` class. In real case there is a lot of classes that relates in complex tree

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wE7Eym)?  But I'm not very confident or happy with this.  Why not just have an empty root for the top of the tree?  Why should it point to itself so that the data structure is explicitly circular?

Comment: @jcalz Each class has its own context that uses methods of that class. But if the parent is passed, then the context changes. Since the entire initial context can belong to any instance, it must be returned after any operations. This had to be done because the context of the tree may change (i.e. a parent may become a child of its child, and a child of its parent, may appear other parent/child, etc.)

Comment: @jcalz I got the principal of your last example and can adjust it to suit of needs. Please post your code as an answer